# How Do I get the server key for Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying to learn google places API,for that we need API key and server key.I am able to get the API key while creating the project in the google console .I am unable to create server key which be used as key while working with google places API.

Can Anybody tell us how to create the server key?

Comment: Do you use Places API web service or Places API for Android?

Comment: I used place API fro Android

Comment: The official documentation mentions only API key with Android app restriction: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup. Would you mind explaining where you found that server key is required and what exactly is server key.

Comment: i am working on the google maps places API to find Nearby places.I have checked this tutorial https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-nearby-places-api-using-retrofit-android/

Comment: here they are generating server key apart from API key

Comment: The tutorial is a bit out of date. Currently, server key means an API key with IP restrictions. You can use the API key with Android app restriction for Places API for Android and Google Maps Android API, but you will need an API key with IP restrictions or without restrictions to execute web service requests. In this case it will be Places API nearby search which is not available in Places API for Android and is available only in web service. So just generate a second API key to use it with web services.

Comment: Thanks for your suggession